# Loop/Recurse in MatLab

Tags: matlab, list, loops, recursion

Just started teaching myself MatLab (python background) and I just want to iterate through a simple list of function outputs. I have for example F1 through to F7 as outputs from 7 different functions and I want to put them in a list and return the minimum output value from that list. How would I go about doing this? I know that MatLab uses arrays instead of lists just not sure where to start. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The basic data type of Matlab is matrix which can be any dimensional array. There's no python like `list` here and you can do the following to achieve what you've asked.

```
 % Let's say you've value through F1 through F7

 data = [F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7];  % creating matrix with the value F1 through F7
 min_value = min(data);
 disp(min_value);
```

You can do it in Old Fashioned `loop` structure too.

```
% Let's say you've value through F1 through F7

 data = [F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7];  % creating matrix with the value F1 through 
 F7
 min_value = intmax;
 for i =1:7
    if(min_value > data(i))
       min_value=data(i);
    end
 end
 disp(min_value);
```